# Using GarageBand + Jam Packs in commercial games for iPhone

Tags: mac, audio, music, garageband

I already read this : http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201808

But I have a question...

1.Are we allowed to use sound effects from GarageBand as sound effects in our game without any modifications of original sound ?

For example I need an effect when button is clicked, or bullet is fired, or coin is collected, or I just need background music and for some of those effects I don't want to create new ones by myself...I just want them as they are already. Can I use GarageBand for that just by simply purchasing an app and use it's predefined effects, or loops, in my iPhone commercial game ? Also how does the same thing applies to Jam packs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article your linked is pretty clear: as long as you don't *SELL* the loops or tracks *as* loops or tracks, you can use them as you wish. Same would apply to the Jam Packs.